# How to print characters like \0 \a \b \v \f

Tags: python, string

In Python3

```
>>> '\t'
'\t'
```

This is what I expect

```
>>> '\0 \a \b \v \f'
'\x00 \x07 \x08 \x0b \x0c'
```

I don't want the hex values

```
>>> '\\0 \\a \\b \\v \\f'
'\\0 \\a \\b \\v \\f'
```

This doesn't work either.
How do I print these characters as shown '\0 \a \b \v\ f'?  I can print characters like \t, but cant print these for some reason.

Comment: What you are seeing is the default `repr` available through the interactive interpreter.  If you want to see the printed output, you should pass the input through the `print` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you input your string in a function such as print, it works:

```
>>> print('\\0 \\a \\b \\v \\f')
\0 \a \b \v \f
```